# What are the differences between class diagram and physical class diagram?

Tags: uml, tool-uml

What are the differences between class diagram and physical class diagram?

Comment: This is probably better asked on Programmers.Stackexchange, as it's a 'whiteboard question' not a 'keyboard question'.

Comment: Try to get this migrated rather than double posting....

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like a Physical Class Diagram, just class diagrams (you may consult Superstructures if you like). What you probably mean is the difference between class **model** and physical model. The latter focuses on the concrete implementation of a class model. It shows libs, hardware and things you'd need to implement your more abstract class model on some real hardware. With the MDA this part is called PSM (platform specific model) in contrast to the PIM (platform independent model).

Comment: Notice: PIM = **platform**-independent model, and PSM = **platform**-specific model.

Comment: @gwag: getting late here. Time for bed. Will correct.Thanks